# Import "pymongo" could not to be resolved

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to create a database with mongodb and python and I installed pymongo library with the following command:

```
sudo pip3 install pymongo
```

But when trying to run the application, the error appears stating that pymongo is not installed:
[pymongo error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOgQ3.png)

I use VS Code to program in Python and the python interpreter is located at `/home/paulo/Python-3.8.2`

But pymongo was installed in [this location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mTto.png), but I didn't select it

Comment: Please post code and errors in text format, not as images. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15497888)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple versions of python installed. It is installing to python3.7 instead of the 3.8 you are using.

You can force it to install to your default python environment (which should be 3.8) by using `sudo python -m pip install pymongo`. I cannot tell if you're using macOS or linux. if you're using linux you can also typically use `sudo python3.8 -m pip install pymongo`.

This will let you run the pip command with your default python command install.
Using -m will let you use that default python version to run pip instead of the one set in your ~/.bashrc file.

Alternatively you can go into your `~/.bashrc` file and change the `pip3` alias to the correct version of python. You can find the correct version by using `which python` which will give you the location of your default python install.

Comment: I tried to install using the command: `sudo python3.8 -m pip install pymongo` and it appears to have it installed, but in VS it still doesn't recognize the library. I can't access `~/.bashrc`. A permission denied warning appears

Comment: @pauloguilherme Once you install it you will need to restart VS code so it can reimport the new pip packages

Comment: I restarted. The error keeps appearing

Answer (score 0):

The scenario that @KieranWood mentioned was also my case. My solution was to remove the older version of python and do a symlink for the new one like this:

`sudo apt-get remove python2.7
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python
I also added a line to the libs in .bashrc:
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages`